# Use raspberry pi as an interface for openocd on cc2538

Tags: raspberry-pi, openocd

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://gist.github.com/hwhw/fc43892785aa84913d03495c97b0f25a) to activate serial bootloader on cc2538 using raspberry pi and OpenOCD.
After connecting micro controller is seen by OpenOCD `Info : JTAG tap: cc2538.jrc tap/device found: 0x8b96402f (mfg: 0x017 (Texas Instruments), part: 0xb964, ver: 0x8)`
but then I getting `Error: Invalid ACK (6) in DAP response` and I can't proceed.

I tried Raspberry Pi 2 and 4. OpenOCD package from repository and freshly build from source.

Thanks for any help.